# Crossing a symbol like p, similar to HBAR

Tags: syntax, display, built-in-symbols

Is it possible in Mathematica to cross a symbol like p, similar to h-bar, used to denote the Planck constant?

Picture in case of font problems:

[image]

In case of h, we have HBAR, inputted as ESC-hb-ESC but there is no similar ESC-pbar-ESC defined.

This is a re-phrasing of a TeX question that has a solution in TeX:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/crossing-a-symbol-like-p-similar-to-one-like-hbar?noredirect=1&lq=1

Thank you for all suggestions.

Comment: This does not exactly answer your question, but [that glyph already exists](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/character-map-unicode-symbol.php?chid=0584). Try [`FromCharacterCode[1412]`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FY4Pt.png).

Comment: or perhaps `FromCharacterCode[42833]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll I found the reference, but the code evaluates to a boxed question mark on my system (MMA 11.2, Win7-64). Is that an encoding / OS / configuration issue?

Comment: @MarcoB: indeed, it does not answer the question. I am looking for a general way to cross a symbol by a bar. Turns out I actually need "b-bar" not "p-bar". I just didn't have the graphics to illustrate a "b-bar".

Comment: @Ohcolowisc Like [this glyph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ƀ)?

Comment: something like this? `RawBoxes@OverscriptBox["b",AdjustmentBox["\[HorizontalLine]", BoxBaselineShift-> 1.125]]`